# Characterize kernels of monoid homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

The kernel of a monoid homomorphism $f : M \to M'$ is the submonoid $\{m \in M : f(m)=1\}$. (This should not be confused with the kernel pair, which is often also named the kernel.)

*Question.* Which submonoids $N$ of a given monoid $M$ arise as the kernel of a monoid homomorphism? (If necessary, let us assume that $M$ is commutative.)

Here is a necessary condition: If $xy \in N$, then $x \in N \Leftrightarrow y \in N$.

Comment: Is the cancellation law part of the definition of "monoid" for you? (For me it is, which might make my answer no good for your purpose.)

Comment: A monoid is a triple $(X,\cdot,1)$, where $X$ is a set, $\cdot$ is an associative binary operation on $X$, and $1$ is a neutral element for this operation. This is the standard definition. I have never seen anyone who included the cancellation law into the definition. Then, one speaks of cancellable monoids.

Comment: The word "wrong" is a bit strange in the context of a discussion about a definition/terminology.  I am certainly not the only one to use the convention that a monoid is assumed cancellative (I'd call your monoids semigroup with identity).  [But I grant it may well be less common than yours, which is why I asked about it.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $(M,\cdot,1)$ be a monoid. A submonoid $N$ of $M$ is a kernel of some homorphism if and only if $y_1,..,y_n \in N$, then $x_1y_1...x_ny_n\in N \Leftrightarrow x_1...x_n \in N$. One implication is trivial. For the other we need to generate a congruence from $N$. Let $R$ be the transitive closure of the following set $$S=\{(a,b)\,|\,\exists a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_m \in M, x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m\in N\ x_1a_1...x_na_n=y_1b_1...y_mb_m,\, a=a_1...a_n,\, b=b_1...b_m\}$$ which is submonoid of $M\times M$ and is reflexive and symmetric. Note that $R$ is hence a congruence. Let $q:M\to M/R$ be the canonical quotient. We will show that $N$ is the kernel of $q$. i.e. we need to show that if $(a,1)$ is $R$, then $a$ is in $N$. Let us begin by showing that if $(a,b)$ is in $S$ and $b$ is in $N$, then $a$ is in $N$. Accordingly suppose there exists $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_m\in M$, $x_1,...,x_n, y_1,...,y_m\in N$ such that $a=a_1...a_n$, $b=b_1...b_m$ and $x_1a_1...x_na_n=y_1b_1...y_mb_m$. We have $$b=b_1...b_m\in N \Rightarrow x_1a_1...x_na_n=y_1b_1...y_mb_m \in N \Rightarrow a=a_1...a_n \in N.$$ Now suppose that $(a,1)$ is in $R$, then there exists $u_1,...,u_p$ such that $u_1=a$, $u_p=1$ and $(u_i,u_{i+1}) \in S$. We have $(u_{p-1},u_p) \in S$ and $u_p=1$ is in $N$ which implies that $u_{p-1}$ is in $N$. Repeating we find that $a$ is in $N$ as required.

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that when $M$ is commutative the condition above reduces to the one mentioned in the question, and given $N$ the congruence $R$ above is simply $$R=\{(a,b)\,|\,\exists x,y\in N\, xa=yb\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Don't we also need the symmetric condition (in the proof): $y_1 x_1 \cdots y_n x_n \in N \Leftrightarrow x_1 \cdots x_n \in N$?

Comment: Also, your $n$ in the last sentences should probably be $p$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The symmetric condition follows from the above condition: $y_1x_1...y_nx_n=1y_1x_1...y_nx_n1 \Leftrightarrow 1x_1...x_n=x_1...x_n \in N$ (i.e. apply the above condition with $x'_1=1,x'_i=x_{i-1}$ and $y'_i=y_i, y'_{n+1}=1$)

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

**A late answer**.

Nex's answer is correct, but can be simplified as follows.
Let $N$ be a submonoid of $M$. Then there exists a congruence $\sim$ on $M$ such that $N = [1]_\sim$ if and only if, 
$$
  \text{(C) for all $x,y \in M$ and for all $u \in N$, $xuy \in N \iff xy\in N$.}
$$
Condition (C) is necessary since $u \sim 1$ implies $xuy \sim xy$. To prove it is sufficient, consider the *syntactic congruence of $N$*, which is the congruence $\sim_N$ on $M$ defined by $u \sim_N v$ if and only if, for all $x, y \in M$,
$$
  xuy \in N \iff xvy \in N
$$
Condition (C) just says that $[1]_{\sim_N} = N$, which concludes the proof.

**A side remark**. The term *kernel* should probably be reserved to the *kernel category of a monoid homomorphism*. See the papers [1, 2, 3] for references and these [slides](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/Exposes/Kernels-6v.pdf) for a quick overview.

[1] S. Margolis and J.-É. Pin, [Inverse semigroups and extensions of groups by semilattices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387900469), *J. of Algebra* **110** (1987), 277-297.

[2] B. Tilson, [Categories as algebra: an essential ingredient in the theory of monoids](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404987901083), *J. Pure Appl. Algebra* **48** (1987), no. 1-2, 83--198.

[3] B. Steinberg and B. Tilson, Categories as algebra II, *Internat. J. Algebra Comput.* **13** (2003), no. 6, 627--703.